# Overwriting content of command line in .txt file

Tags: linux, command-line, debian

The output of the following command line :

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -af astats=metadata=1:reset=10,ametadata=print:key=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level -f null /dev/null 2> volume.txt
```

continuously outputs this data :

```
[Parsed_ametadata_1 @ 0x7fbae6209ac0] lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-22.294513
[Parsed_ametadata_1 @ 0x7fbae6209ac0] frame:32   pts:36864   pts_time:0.835918
[Parsed_ametadata_1 @ 0x7fbae6209ac0] lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-22.194567
[Parsed_ametadata_1 @ 0x7fbae6209ac0] frame:33   pts:38016   pts_time:0.862041
[Parsed_ametadata_1 @ 0x7fbae6209ac0] lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-22.197214
```

and so on continuously...

But what I need it to do is to overwrite the content overwrite with just the current outputted value so the content of the .txt file only ever contains this data, which is the latest outputted data fro mthe above command line :

```
[Parsed_ametadata_1 @ 0x7fbae6209ac0] frame:33   pts:38016   pts_time:0.862041
[Parsed_ametadata_1 @ 0x7fbae6209ac0] lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-22.197214
```

Instead of appending each time it updates the .txt file which grows all the time because it is being appended to.

How would I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While a command is running synchronously, and you redirect it's output to a file, you can't filter it, if not with a different process, but this solution implies a big overload, poses many problems and is really difficult to implement; in summary, it's not what you want.
I think what you want is to **watch** the last two lines of your output file.
You can achieve this, running (in a different terminal than the `ffmpeg` running command, or running `ffmpeg` in background), something like:

```
$ watch tail -n 2 volume.txt
```

Which shows any time only the last two lines in your `volume.txt` file.

**UPDATE**
If you can't accept your log filg to grow indefinitely, the only solution I see to reach a result *similar* to the one you ask for is:

- run your command with `>>` insead of `>`, to be able to truncate output file while streaming, and run it in background; so:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -af astats=metadata=1:reset=10,ametadata=print:key=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level -f null /dev/null 2>> volume.txt &
  ```
- then, truncate (remove) the log file every one second (or more, according to the speed of your log producer); so, for example:

  ```
  while [ -f volume.txt ]; do sleep 1; rm -f volume.txt; done
  ```

Hopefully this way you can have *1 second* lines of log data in your file, avoiding it to grow indefinitely...

Comment: Thank you for replying. While this would work, the file would grow indefinitely which is not really an acceptable solution as it is a live stream (i only indicated it was a file for illustration) but as it is a live stream file, the file would grow indefinitely.